# lookup on date ranges in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which looks like this. Note that `KeyColumn` values are from a finite pool.

```
StartDate      EndDate       KeyColumn
01/01/2016     05/01/2016    Key1
05/01/2016     10/01/2016    Key2
11/01/2016     20/01/2016    Key1
```

They are sorted. Next `StartDate` is greater than or equal to the current `EndDate`.

What I want to do is creating the following sheet with a kind of lookup. Each key column can be created manually.

```
Date           Key1          Key2
01/01/2016     True          False
02/01/2016     True          False
03/01/2016     True          False
04/01/2016     True          False
05/01/2016     True          True
06/01/2016     False         True
```

`02/01/2016` is `True` for `Key1` because it is in the range of the first row in the first table which has the value `Key1`.

`05/01/2016` is `True` for `Key1` and `Key2` because it is in the range of the first row and the second row.

Is this possible in google spreadsheet without using any scripts? I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with creative use of the filter and count functions:

[image]

Comment: He want to get key of date between in interval not just beginning or end, apply formula for 06/01/2016 to know what i mean

Comment: Good catch, @Chemiadel, thanks. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

i used query function to solve that the formula

```
=iferror(hlookup(B$8,transpose( QUERY({arrayformula(days($A$2:$B$4,)),$C$2:$C$4},"select Col3 where Col1<="& days($A9,) &" and Col2>= " & days($A9,) ,-1)),1,False)=B$8,False)
```

or

```
=iferror(hlookup(B$8,transpose(query($A$2:$C$4,"Select C Where toDate(A) < date '" & text(A9, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' " & " and toDate(B) > date '" & text(A9, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ",-1)),1,False)=B$8,False)
```

[image]